# Spring Integration DSL Stackoverflow Error

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We are using Spring Integration Java DSL and intermittently we are observing stackoverflow error , and from stack-trace , we observe the infinite loop too . But unable to figure out why its happening intermittently and why not always .

Stacktrace we see is:

```
 

        at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:93)
        ... 992 more
    Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.net.ManagedSocketInputStreamAPSIHighPerformanceNew.read(ManagedSocketInputStreamAPSIHighPerformanceNew.java:100)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
        at org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.fillInputBuffer(BHttpConnectionBase.java:344)
        at org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.isStale(BHttpConnectionBase.java:364)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool.validate(CPool.java:69)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool.validate(CPool.java:43)
        at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.getPoolEntryBlocking(AbstractConnPool.java:247)
        at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.access$000(AbstractConnPool.java:64)
        at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.getPoolEntry(AbstractConnPool.java:192)
        at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.getPoolEntry(AbstractConnPool.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.pool.PoolEntryFuture.get(PoolEntryFuture.java:107)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:276)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:263)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsConnection.onSendAfterWrite(HttpComponentsConnection.java:120)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:48)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:658)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:606)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
        at org.springframework.integration.ws.MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:87)
        at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:188)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:178)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor729.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$1.execute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:75)
        at com.bofa.paycom.ci.advice.TxnTraceAdvice.doInvoke(TxnTraceAdvice.java:71)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1080.handleRequestMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.doInvokeAdvisedRequestHandler(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:112)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)`enter code here`
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
```

These set of lines is being looped :

```
<pre><code>
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
```

Any help or pointers will help .

My Integration flow looks as below :

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow lxxDownstreamNotificationFlow() {

        LOGGER.info("Inside the downstream notification flow - lcmDownstreamNotificationFlow()");   
        return IntegrationFlows.from(lxxDownstreamNotificationChannel)
                .handle(lxxNotificationProcessor)
                .gateway(requestxxxxxxxEventLogger)
                .channel("lxxCoreReplyChannel")
                .get();
    }
```

I could not find any flow/component where inputChannel & OutPutChannel is same . But we have some common utility flow , which is used , somewhere it sense me is this causing the issue .

Gateway which I mentioned earlier is routing to below integration flow

```
@Component
public final class EventLoggingFlow implements IntegrationFlow {

    private Long eventId;
    private String message;

    @Autowired
    private EventPublishingHandler eventPublishingHandler;

    public EventLoggingFlow() {
    }
    public EventLoggingFlow(Long eventId, String message) {
        super();
        this.eventId = eventId;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> t) {
        t   .fixedSubscriberChannel()
            .enrichHeaders(new Consumer<HeaderEnricherSpec>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(HeaderEnricherSpec t) {
                 t.headerExpression(HeaderKeys.SOURCE, "payload.sourceChannel");
                }
            })
            .enrich(new EventEnricherSpec(eventId, message))
            .publishSubscribeChannel(eventPublishingHandler)
            .handle(new BridgeHandler());
    }
}
Publish/Subscribe flow is implemented as below :

@Component
@DependsOn("eventSubcriberFlow")
public class EventPublishingHandler implements Consumer<PublishSubscribeSpec> {

    @Autowired
    private EventSubcriberFlow eventSubcriberFlow;

    @Override
    public void accept(PublishSubscribeSpec t) {
        t.subscribe(eventSubcriberFlow);
    }    
}


@Component
public class EventSubcriberFlow implements IntegrationFlow {

    @Autowired 
    private EventSubscribingHandler eventSubscribingHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> flow) {
        flow.fixedSubscriberChannel()
            .handle(eventSubscribingHandler)
            .channel("nullChannel");
    }

}
```

Is fixedSubscriberChannel() causing a looping ?

Answer (score 0):

The typical error for this kind of behavior is about sending outputs to the channel where its flow ends up on this channel as well and resend message again. It’s hard to say where, but according stack trace there is something with calling SOAP service and you don’t show that.

Comment: What may is a debug logs for spring Integration category and then in logs you can see how your message travels and where that loop starts. Also you can turn on message history to track the path: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-history